# How to obtain a periodic function from a rapidly decaying function?

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

Suppose $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ with $x \in [0, 3]$. How could I periodise this function to obtain an analytical form of a continuum periodic function $x \in [0, +\infty)$ with period T = 3?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do this in any straighforward manner. Look at the derivatives at the boundary - they don't match if you simply "paste another copy of $f(x)$". The result wouldn't be $C^1$, let alone analytic.

Comment: Why not $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(x-3n)^2}$?

Comment: @MattL. Not quite periodic :) to get a periodic function one needs to sum over *all* integers, even though only the behavior on positive semiaxis is of interest.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier: Obvioulsy you're right, but in practice there would hardly be any difference because $e^{-x^2}$ decays very fast. Anyway, the result seemed so trivial that by my comment I just wanted to make sure whether the OP meant something different from the obvious solution.

Answer (score 3):

Given a  function $f$ with rapid decay at infinity, one can obtain a "periodic" version of it by summation of translates: 
$$F(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty f(x-nT)\tag1$$
For your function this results in $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-3n)^2}$.

Note that the function shown on your graph actually has period $T=6$, not $3$. With the period $3$ we get something that looks suspiciously similar to the cosine curve:

[image: periodization]

Observe that the shape of $f$ is not exactly preserved in the sum. If you want it to be preserved, you can still use (1), but make sure that $f$ vanishes outside of an interval of length $T$. E.g., let $f(x) = e^{-x^2}\chi_{[-T/2,T/2]}$.

<sup>(Expanding the comment by Matt L.)</sup>